# Express: npm test returns "connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, compoundjs

I'm trying to test my app, and it always returns an error of **connect ECONNREFUSED**.  I made a simple example to show what's happening.  Here's my controller (CompoundJS code):

```
load('application');

action('test', function() {
  var obj = {success: true, data: 'blah'};
  send(obj);
});

action(function show(data) {
  var http = require('http');
  var options = {
    path: '/getTest',
    port: process.env.PORT  // without this, http fails because default port is 80
  };
  var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      return send(data);
    });
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    return send({success: false, data: e.message}); // returns "connect ECONNREFUSED"
  });
});
```

So when I have the app running, I can hit **/test** (which is the show method there) and **/getTest** just fine without any errors.  However, when I try to run the following test code, I get the error as stated above, and the issue comes down to that http.get, as I can get into the show function just fine.

```
var app, compound
  , request = require('supertest')
  , sinon = require('sinon');

function TestStub() {
  return {
  };
}

describe('TestController', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    app = getApp();
    compound = app.compound;
    compound.on('ready', function() {
      done();
    });
  });

  /*
   * GET /tests
   * Should render tests/index.ejs
   */
  it('should render "index" template on GET /tests', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/test')
      .end(function(err, res) {
      console.log(res.body);
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Cross posted from the [CompoundJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compoundjs/hi7WfsxEa8U).

Comment: This is an eval controller, which gets wrapped in a `new Function` at some point. I don't think it's the problem you're seeing, but you may have problems with the `require` later since it's a method of `module` and may not be available. I recommend using `noeval` controllers, which are normal modules and have none of the global magic function silliness (`load` etc.). Seriously.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I shall try changing it to a `noeval` and see if my mileage varies.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No promises. ;) I'm currently facing a huge refactor away from a bunch of old eval controllers, and I wouldn't wish it on anyone!

Comment: Just an update... I did move my controller to a `noeval` controller, but it did not fix the issue.  Regardless, it made me more aware of eval vs. noeval, and I will be using noeval from now on.  So at the very least, thanks for that!